# How to validate Text Box From Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I want to validate a Text box between 0 - 100 (including decimal values '12.5'). Problem is in my website used deference languages. so that  below code work for English but not working for Dutch language because they are used ',' to '.'.

```
<div class="medium-6 columns">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textAdvPacPrecentage" class="PriceEditoTxtBox left PriceEditorAdminFee" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                    <p>%</p>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                        Text="*" ControlToValidate="textAdvPacPrecentage" ValidationGroup="SavePriceList"
                        ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pr-req" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{1,2}){1}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="clientAdvancePacPerecentage" runat="server" Text="*" Display="Dynamic"
                        ToolTip="Advance package percentage invalid number" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pr-req" ControlToValidate="textAdvPacPrecentage"
                        ValidationGroup="SavePriceList" />
                </div>
```

[dys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hercs.png)

Need a solution for that.

Comment: I posted the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543900/3832970) supporting both English and Dutch decimal separator formats.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
ValidationExpression="^(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?|100(?:[.,]0{1,2})?)$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jOuGQm/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?|100(?:[.,]0{1,2})?)` - Non-capturing group matching one of the two alternatives:

  - `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?` - a digit from `0` to `9` or numbers from `10` to `99` (see the `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)` part) and then an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then one or two digits (see the `(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?` part)
  - `|` - or
  - `100(?:[.,]0{1,2})?` - `100` that is followed with an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then one or two `0` chars.
- `$` - end of string

Comment: your regex does not captures numbers like 9.123, https://regex101.com/r/XBr62L/2

Comment: @Predicate And it should not, see `(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` in the OP regex.

Comment: But he stated all fractional numbers from 0 to 100. 9.123 is beeing one of them.

Comment: I see now, he putted it in the regex. Correct. But the Problem statement was not clear about that

Comment: @Predicate You are thinking up requirements. There is no `9.123` example in the question, and the original regex does not match numbers with 3 or more digits in the fractional part. We should not change those parts of the regex that the question does not relate to. Let OP provide feebback.

Comment: I can understand your point, and you are correct. But the Problem description is to vague. For  example it is totally not clear if 100.12 should match. "up to 100" actually means that it should not.

Comment: @Predicate I know what you mean, but I have seen so many questions like this that I am 99.9% sure this is what OP meant.

Answer (score -1):

User this regex

```
^(([1-9]?\d|100)([\.,]\d?[1-9])?)$
```

demo 
https://regex101.com/r/XBr62L/5

Comment: You are not answering the current question. 1) Does not validate 0 - 100 numbers, 2) Does not match fractional parts (with Dutch number format support as per OP requirements).

Comment: You does not specified it. You said decimal. Decimal means base 10. Fractional could be denoted like real numbers. Please be clear in your description. I did what you asked.

Comment: decimal means I want to enter 12.5, 55.75 decimal values

Comment: Thats not what decimal means in math. You waht real or fractional numbers. Using hte word decimal could confuse.

Comment: Are whole numbers allowed? like 20? without fractions? can 100 have fractions like 100.1 or is 100 the biggest number?

Comment: Are you trying validate percentages?